# .net core 2.2 with typescript and signalr

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core, signalr

I'd like to have ASP.NET core 2.2 with TypeScript and Signalr, but I do not know, how to correctly setup project.

I have installed @aspnet/signalr npm package to project root with`npm install @aspnet/signalr`. So my project root looks like this:

```
Controllers/
Models/
node_modules/
Properties/
TypeScript/
Views/
wwwroot/
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.json
MyProject.csproj
package-lock.json
package.json
Program.cs
Startup.cs
tsconfig.json
```

Having this TypeScript/home.ts file:

```
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";

const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/gameHub").build();


connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, color) {
    console.log("color " + color + "; user " + user);
    let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById(user).getElementsByClassName("board")[0];
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
});
```

And finally my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

When I use in tsconfig.json `"target": "es2017",`, then VS cannot find @aspnet/signalr and I can't run project. When I switch it to `"target": "es5",`, then VS can find @aspnet/signalr, but it generates home.js with following line: `Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });` and it throws an error in browser.

I guess that my tsconfig.json is not properly setup. Also I would like to use ES6 modules in browser if possible (https://www.sitepoint.com/using-es-modules/)

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am still looking for a solution where I can use ES6 modules in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-typescript-webpack?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Normaly you have to target `es5` to run in web project in the browser. he turtorial show you how to setup typescript with webpack because we need to compile ts to js

Please let me know if you need any help

Comment: That is what worked for me, but I kind of expected to do it without webpack. I do not like the idea of having thousands of different tools and apps running to do one thing. I thought that it can be done only with correct setting in tsconfig.json. Thanks

Comment: maybe you need to config your vs to build ts to js

Comment: btw. why do I have to target es5? can't I use for example es2017? I would like to use modules also in browser since they should be supported.

Comment: es5 to target supported browser like IE